# How to read text file and store in a vector of classes - Android

Tags: java, android, c++

I want to read a text file into my android program and store the contents in a vector of classes. A sample of the contents of the text file is shown below:

```
Latitude  Longitude  Radioactivity
56.0349  -3.34267    8690000
56.0328  -3.342      867289
56.0328  -3.342      867289
56.0348  -3.34242    404430
56.0348  -3.34247    295287
56.0338  -3.34122    221830
56.0346  -3.34242    193347
56.0337  -3.34118    182304
56.0342  -3.34141    155572
56.0337  -3.34173    145229
56.0347  -3.34239    125143
```

I want to store these values in a vector (or an array since the list is of finite length) so that I can access the list in a for loop to compare the users current position to the list of points (like geofencing except I have a database of points).

I have already done this in c++ but I have not programmed in java before and this is my first android app. Below is my c++ code. My question is, how do I do the same thing in java for my android app??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct radioactivityData
{
double lat;
double lon;
int radioactivity;
};

int main()
{
std::ifstream dataFile;
dataFile.open("combinedorderedData.txt");

std::string tmpLine;
std::vector<radioactivityData> radioactivityTable;

while(std::getline(dataFile, tmpLine))
{
    std::stringstream inputLine(tmpLine);

    radioactivityData rad;
    if(!(inputLine >> rad.lat >> rad.lon >> rad.radioactivity))
    {
        // ... error parsing input. Report the error
        // or handle it in some other way.

        continue;   // keep going!
    }
    radioactivityTable.push_back(rad);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic way to read file line by line:

```
private void processFile(Context context, String fileName) {
    BufferedReader br;

    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + FILE_DIR, fileName);
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("couldn't read from external file");
        return;
    }

    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // here you put your code
            processLine(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("couldn't process line");
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Failed to close BufferedReader");
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a way to create the required RadioactivityData object from the line string:

```
private ArrayList<RadioactivityData> mRadioactivityList = new ArrayList<RadioactivityData>();

private void processLine(String line) {

    RadioactivityData radioactivityData = new RadioactivityData(line);
    mRadioactivityList.add(radioactivityData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to also store the data in a constructor like in my c++ code.

Comment: Edited the answer. you can store the data in an ArrayList.

Comment: So In the first code block, where it says //Here you put your code, is that where I need to parse the data and store it in the relevant parts of the mRadioactivityList. Also, you said "assumming you have a way to create the required RadioactivityData object from the line string". What do you mean? That I have to create the object in Java similar to how I did in the c++ code?  Sorry, I am really new to java and android development but I need to make my program for Monday :S

Comment: I actually wrote the processLine method for you. the only thing you need to do is define the RadioactivityData class. I also tipped you on that you can have a constructor to RadioactivityData which excepts String as its parameter. parsing the string can be done by using String[] lineParts = line.split("[ ]"); and than use the lineParts for the lat, long, radioactivity...
That is as far as I can go. you have to learn Java..

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try and learn Java, its just that I have a project which requires me to use a current GPS position and compare it to the database of positions with different levels of radioactivity. It would go through a loop and measure the distance from you position to the positions in the database and if you were say <15 meters from one of the sources it would send an alert. This is similar to geofencing however I have 500 or so datapoints so I wanted to make my own program. I have all the ideas and know the logic behind how it should work its just I don't know any Java.

Comment: I need to use the android to access the GPS. So since this project is due Monday I don't really have time to learn. By the way this is an Architecture project so I am not being marked on programming.

Comment: you should accept my answer as I answered your question fully. you can open new questions for GPS and other stuff.